# Cheap keyboard piano sounds vs Youtube recording

Tags: keyboard

I'm currently learning my first piano piece with a cheap keyboard (Casio CTK 611), but I've started to wonder if I should upgrade to a proper E-Piano (e.g. P-125B).

The reason is that some sounds/keys of my keyboard (used with high-quality headphones), feel significantly off compared to the Youtube version of the piano piece that I'm learning.

Consider this part for example, the notes ♭H1, C2, ♭D2 & ♭E3, F3, G3, ♭D4 in measure 11 & 12:

Playing these notes with my keyboard, the sound is significantly more "dark" and feels lower in pitch, while the recording sounds "brighter" and "happier", especially for the bass clef.
(Phone-) recording of my keyboard playing the same notes:
https://soundcloud.com/michael-moser-14/myrec-0215-2155

However, the same applies to virtual pianos that you can find online, e.g. https://virtualpiano.net. They sound like my keyboard, a lot darker.

So I'm wondering if the discrepancy in sound is based on my cheap keyboard and if I should upgrade, or if it is based on a non-usual piano sound in the video (it's seemingly played with the professional *Finale* program)? I.e., can I expect to get a similar sound with a proper e-piano?

Comment: Just want to say I’ve owned and played extensively on a P-125 and it is a great option in its price range.

Comment: To best answer the question, we'd need to hear your keyboard playing the same passage. However, the tone quality of the instrument used in the recording is quite bad, so even though the pitch is accurate, it's easy to imagine it sounds quite different from your keyboard.

Comment: The video seems to be a MIDI playback of the score. That's not a good reference. What you want to know about a piano is how it responds to dynamics, both on the mechanical level, as well as sample quality. As Aaron said, you need to send example of your playing on the piano, otherwise there is no way for us to guess what problem there is to solve.

Comment: Here is a recording, unfortunately only made with my phone, don't know if this will help : https://soundcloud.com/michael-moser-14/myrec-0215-2155. Nevertheless, it's already good to know that the YT sound is not what I should expect it to be on a real piano. Because this was impossible to judge for me.

Comment: Additional note if that helps: my keyboard sounds very similar to the virtual piano link that I posted.

Comment: Hi, when you talk about your keyboard being "very far off" sounding the same as that recording, or a "discrepancy in sound", or "sounds very similar", or "sound is not what I should expect it to be", it is not possible to know exactly what you are saying. Do you mean the pitch is wrong? Or are you saying the piano sound is unrealistic? Or what. Please edit your question to state the actual problem in precise terms, otherwise it isn't really possible to know what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've tried to make it more clear in the question.

Comment: Tiny nitpick: I'd say "digital piano", not "e-piano".  I usually assume an "electric piano" means a Fender Rhodes or a Wurlitzer or some other such non-digital instrument.  Maybe that's just me.

Comment: Judging by ear, you need totally flat key velocity response, mid-scooped EQ and encoding through low bit rate codec to match the video. In my opinion it is not worth emulating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn piano, then something with 88 weighted keys like the Yamaha you're considering is a good idea.

That said, you probably still won't be able to match the sound from that recording exactly.  The fact is, different pianos sound different, sometimes very different.  This is true both for acoustic pianos and digital pianos.  Work on the notes, timing, duration, dynamics, expression, etc., and generally on making music that you like, and don't obsess about matching somebody else's tone exactly.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember is that it's not trivial to have a recording of a real piano sound better than a (non-acoustic) recording of a digital piano since the digital piano sounds are usually created from high-quality acoustic pianos.  Of course, playing at different volumes and with simultanous notes and pedalling, the complexity is higher than just adding one sound per note adjusted in timing and amplification, but in first approximation, this is close.

In the same room live, the digital pianos have a hard time keeping up, but once recorded, the difference becomes a lot more subtle.  Better digital pianos tend to provide a quite better graded/weighted resistance/response to your finger strikes, more so than they make a difference in sound.

This differentiated keyboard response may at some point of time provide incentive to upgrade.  The produced sound, particularly when recorded, is likely making for less of an obvious difference.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!
I was already thinking about investing in a better quality e-piano in the mid-term due to the keyboard response, mechanics etc., as you already mentioned. I was just a little bit confused, since the sound from the recording is really far off from my (cheap) keyboard sound. And I didn't want to buy a fresh e-piano just to find out that the YT video just sounds off.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, reproducing the sounds you hear on YouTube might be difficult. I will say that, if you can afford an upgrade you will likely not regret it.

As for the brightness you're looking for, I use a guitar EQ pedal to brighten the sound of my Roland RD700.  The Roland sounds great through headphones, but through monitors or PA sounds dull.  I am using a $20 Behringer EQ (Brand new, $20!) right now which is a six-channel EQ.  I may upgrade to a twelve channel for flexibilities sake.  Either way, the EQ makes a profound difference.